# What exactly is the ticks paramerter for yticks/xticks functions in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

What should I pass as ticks parameter of `yticks` function? in matplotlib I don't know if I should pass locations (indices in y arr) or values for y-ticks, documentation describes it as:

> A list of positions at which ticks should be placed

For this program:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,5,9,10,15]
y = ["a","ab","abc","ab","abcd"]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

If I add `plt.xticks([0, 2, 3])` i get ticks with values of: a, abc, abcd. What I don't understand is why ticks aren't: a, abc, ab (locations in y array)? I noticed though, that when vales in y are disctinct locations work as expected.

But when I do `plt.xticks(['as', 'ab', 'acs'])` I get ticks as expected (as ab acs).

So should I use this `tick` parameter as locations, or values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when y = ["a","ab","abc","ab","abcd"], then the ticks are actually ["a","ab","abc","abcd"]. **Note there were two "ab" before but now only one "ab"**.

Now when you say plt.yticks([0, 2, 3]), it choose "a" (index 0), "abc" (index 2), "abcd" (index 3) from ["a","ab","abc","abcd"]

Comment: And when values of y are integers and I give a list of integers to xticks, will they be used as locations, or values?

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, if it is a list of numbers, it will be interpreted as the position of ticks (not index or anything else) and if it is a list of strings, it will be interpreted as the name of ticks. See more details [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html).